# Simplifiying variables in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I simplify the following code?

It is just a static ID.

```
<script>
    $x('input[id="id1"]').attr('checked', true);
    $x('input[id="idx4"]').attr('checked', true);
    $x('input[id="idk5"]').attr('checked', true);
</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the [ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). You can select multiple elements by separating by comma:

```
$x('#id1,#idx4,#idk5').attr('checked', true);
```

Or if you are using jQuery 1.6 (or later) you should be using [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set checked property:

```
$x('#id1,#idx4,#idk5').prop('checked', true);
```

Comment: @LizaMcbell Your Welcome :)  If this answered your question, don't forget to click the green checkmark by the votes

Answer (score 0):

jQuery uses [seletors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) that are similar to CSS, with a few additions. As `[id]` attributes have to be unique, you don't need to specify the element (in this case `input`). You can use the [`id` selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/).

Also, you shouldn't be setting the `checked` attribute, as that changes the value that the checkbox would be reset to, you should be changing the `checked` property instead:

```
$('#id1, #idx4, #idk5').prop('checked', true);
```

To do the same in jQuery pre-1.6:

```
$('#id1, #idx4, #idk5').each(function () {
    this.checked = true;
});
```